# controlgroup('refresh') not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having problems using both enhanceWithin()  and controgroup('refresh'). i posted a question last month about a similar thing[(link)](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/enhancewithin-not-working) and i was help but when i try to apply what i understood it just doesnt work.

My problem is I want all the possible answers in the quiz to look like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mystro/qo8kgL9s/) 2 now this was  how i did it with just one question  but now i want to do multiple questions. this i what i did [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ogzr88m7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var responseText = '{"title":"quiz 3","qid":"63375","qno":"5","dur":"0:30","no":["1","2","3","4","5"],"ques":["test 12","test 324","test 93jk","test5","4gvgfghfgjfjhg"],"a":["bnvbnvn","uyiugyukf","hgd",";opoippoidfd","nbmmnmbn"],"b":["mhhhhm","hjfi","fgfg","uoyurtyytd","fghhvb"],"c":["nmnmnmmn","rythj"," bnbnvbnvbnv","yutuddyc","vmbvmj"],"d":["nnn","iiii","hghjghjmm","yuitdtydddy","vvv"],"e":["mkkmkm","hnvhjnbmhn","gfdrdyrttyjk","45","bnvcnvb"]}';

    var json = $.parseJSON(responseText);
    var title = json['title'];
    var duration = json['dur'];
    var no = json['qno'];
    var ques_m = json['ques'];
    var a = json['a'];
    var b = json['b'];
    var c = json['c'];
    var d = json['d'];
    var e = json['e'];

    var j = 1 //question counter
    var i = 0 // array counter

    while (no > i) {  

        var div = $("<div />");
        var ques = "<p id='ques" + i + "' placeholder='Enter Question Here.'>" + ques_m[i] + "</textarea>";

        var ans_div = $("<div />");
        var ans_a = "<label>" + a[i] + "</label><input type='radio' name='possans" + j + "' id='aans" + i + "' value='" + a[i] + "'/>";
        var ans_b = "<label>" + b[i] + "</label><input type='radio'   name='possans" + j + "'  id='bans" + i + "'value='" + b[i] + "'/>";
        var ans_e = "<label>" + e[i] + "</label><input type='radio'   name='possans" + j + "' id='eans" + i + "' value='" + e[i] + "'/>";
        var ans_c = "<label>" + c[i] + "</label><input type='radio'   name='possans" + j + "' id='cans" + i + "' value='" + c[i] + "'/>";
        var ans_d = "<label>" + d[i] + "</label><input type='radio'   name='possans" + j + "' id='dans" + i + "' value='" + d[i] + "'/>";

        $(ans_div).append(ans_a).append(ans_b).append(ans_c).append(ans_d).append(ans_e);
        $(div).append("Q(" + j + ")").append(ques).append(ans_div);
        i++;
        j++;
        $("#qu").append(div).append("<hr/><br>");
    }

    $("#qu").append("<input type='button' value='Update'onclick='sub()' id='submit'/><input type='hidden' id='count' value='" + no + "'/>");
    $("#qu").enhanceWithin().controlgroup('refresh');

});
```

Comment: Please do not use links with almost no indication of the content behind them, as they may rot away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the `<input>` to each `<label>`: you must use the `for` attribute.

See the **[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogzr88m7/1/)**